# How can I check whether an element is visible with Jest?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library, react-test-renderer

I have a straight forward react-comp. which I want to test the styling depending on the react state. The comp looks like the following:

### React-comp.

```
const Backdrop = ({ showBackdrop }) => {
    const backdropRef = useRef();

    function getBackdropHeight() {
        if (typeof window !== 'undefined') {
            return `calc(${document.body.clientHeight}px -
            ${backdropRef.current?.offsetTop || 0}px)`;
        }

        return 0;
    }

    return (
        <div
            data-testid="backdrop"
            className={classNames(styles.backdrop, showBackdrop ? styles.show : styles.hide)}
            ref={backdropRef}
            style={{ height: getBackdropHeight() }}
        />
    );
};
```

### Styling

```
.backdrop {
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    top: 156px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    z-index: 3;
    ...
}

.show {
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: visibility 0.25s, opacity 0.25s ease-out;
}

.hide {
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: hidden;
    transition: opacity 0.25s ease-in;
}
```

And the error that I always get from the test is, that the element is visible:

```
Received element is visible:
  <div class="backdrop hide" data-testid="backdrop" style="height: calc(0px -
            0px);" />

  21 |         const { getByTestId } = renderWithIntl(<Backdrop showBackdrop={false} />);
  22 | 
> 23 |         expect(getByTestId('backdrop')).not.toBeVisible();
     |                                             ^
  24 |     });
  25 | });
  26 |
```

### Test

```
it("should not render visible backdrop on falsy state", () => {
    const { getByTestId } = render(<Backdrop showBackdrop={false} />);

    expect(getByTestId('backdrop')).not.toBeVisible();
});
```

Any way on how to get the element as not visible without using react inline styling!?

Comment: You may try [`toHaveStyle()`](https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tohavestyle) assertion, passing `'visibility: hidden'` as parameter

Comment: Does not work...the received value is also still `visible`

Comment: Hi. There's a non-straightforward issue with the expectation that css styles coming from a stylesheet are recognized at run time in a jest/jsdom test env. See this comment I once left about it in a jest-dom issue: https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom/issues/113#issuecomment-496971128

Answer (score 8):

You can use `toBeVisible()` function from RTL.
Here you have docs:
https://github.com/testing-library/jest-dom#tobevisible

Example:

```
// element should not be visible on screen
expect(screen.queryByText('1')).not.toBeVisible();
```